# Cursor moves when I tap the touchpad to click (xorg.conf problem)

Tags: 14.04, xorg, touchpad

This may seem as a duplication of:

[Synaptics Touchpad - cursor moves around when just 'tapped' after Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127829/synaptics-touchpad-cursor-moves-around-when-just-tapped-after-ubuntu-12-04-u)

I tried that solution and it works! Setting the FingerHigh and FingerLow values really does the trick, but the xorg.conf file gets renamed to xorg.conf.xxxx (xxxx being random numbers) and then the values of FingerHigh and FingerLow are not the ones I chose anymore.

Any suggestion on how to make this xorg.conf file persistent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add new setting file to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` folder.
There, you can have any file named `NN-filename.conf` with NN is a number of priority. Try to substitute with `99` for priority and `touchpad` to make it clearly describe the purpose (e.g. `99-touchpad.conf`).

In that file, you may add your settings. Something like this will work :

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "touchpad catchall"
  Driver "synaptics"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

  # Change as necessary
  Option "FingerHigh" "25"
  Option "FingerLow" "30"
End Section
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but there is no such folder as xorg.conf.d listed inside /etc/X11.

This is what I get from ls:
roger@latitude:~$ cd /etc/X11/
app-defaults/ cursors/      fonts/        xinit/        xkb/          Xreset.d/     Xresources/   Xsession.d/   xsm/

Comment: I tried creating the folder and the file, but it made my system break upon reboot, then i needed to boot from live cd and delete the /xorg.conf.d in my filesystem, only then i could boot normally again. :/

Comment: Is that so? Try to include only useful option on the file, don't rewrite already-matched option.
Btw, how it was broken? Was the touchpad couldn't be used or something else? (Actually I'm creating that file without problem, Sorry if I pushed you down the hill)